# Fractions in flash

Tags: flash, fractions

I'm looking for a way to display fractions (½, ¼, etc) within a textfield in flash and my first thought was to use html text and a special fraction font. However this would limit the amount of possible fractions and I'm pretty sure I would hit that soon enough. They have to be dynamic with no limitations to both numbers. Now I could create a prepared movieclip with 2 dynamic textfields, however would I be able to embed those in a textfield and also be able to provide them with the 2 parameters needed for the dynamic textfields?

As far as I know, you can embed images in a textfield using html tags.

Or is there another clever approach to this?

[edit] I just found out that you can actually use library linkage names in the img src attribute to embed a movieclip. Using the id attribute you can modify it through actionscript, so I guess that would be the way to set both numbers of the fraction. However it seems the movieclips always get aligned to the left (or positioned in some other arbitrary way) in the textfield which renders this solution useless.

[edit2] Thanks Charles for pointing that out, the painful looking stuff I found on the net makes sense now..

Comment: The term you're looking for is *fraction*, not *fracture*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up just using an x/y notation. I guess I could match the fraction appearance a little more by using a superscript font for x and a subscript font for y.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm taking your example too literally; however, if you only wanted [unicode vulgar fraction math entities](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/mathchart.html), you could embed those characters with your font:

[image: font-embedding]

This would include:

¼ ½ ¾ ⅓ ⅔ ⅕ ⅖ ⅗ ⅘ ⅙ ⅚ ⅛ ⅜ ⅝ ⅞

[Unicode Number Forms](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2150.pdf)

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your reply. There's only a limited set of available fraction characters while it is required for them to be dynamic without limits.